# How to convert an int[] to an OpenCV Mat? (and vice-versa)

Tags: java, arrays, image, opencv, bufferedimage

I am reading bufferedImages in from PNGs, and converting them to int arrays using the PixelGrabber. My question is then: how do I use the integer array to make the corresponding OpenCV Mat? Where the array is 1D, with each value representing a pixel's combined RGB value.

I have already tried using byte arrays.

Comment: What do you mean by combined RGB value?

Comment: What is "combined RGB"? you mean that the first byte of the int is your R value, second G and thirs byte is B value? What is the last byte random value?? You could read each int as a 32 bit RGBA value.

Comment: @Micka whatever happens when you read pixels in from a pixelGrabber, i'm not entirely sure of the data stored in the int. All I know is that to get red its (rgbvalue >> 16) & 0xff; green its (rgbvalue >> 8) & 0xff; and blue is rgbvalue & 0xff; Does this help?

Comment: Unfortunately thats not optimal for opencv so you have to convert your data... Ill give some code later. Basically you can: load data as BGRA. Split channels and reinterpret the channels: B=>waste; G=>R; R=>G; A=>B unless there is a ARGB color type in ppencv then it would be easier and faster...

Comment: ah ok... not as i expected, the ordering is reverse, which is good. I'll give you C++ code which should work very same for java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just interpret the 32 bit int value as a 32 bit RGBA value. I dont know why you dont have to change the order of the channels, but using the int array as input for your `cv::Mat` you automatically get an BGRA ordering. Then you only have to remove the alpha channel, if needed.

```
int main()
{
    // the idea is that each int is 32 bit which is 4 channels of 8 bit color values instead of 3 channels, so assume a 4th channel.

    // first I create fake intArray which should be replaced by your input...
    const int imgWidth = 320;
    const int imgHeight = 210;
    int intArray[imgWidth*imgHeight]; // int array

    // fill the array with some test values:
    for(unsigned int pos = 0; pos < imgWidth*imgHeight; ++pos)
        intArray[pos] = 8453889; // 00000000 10000000 11111111 00000001 => R = 128, G = 255, B = 1
        //intArray[pos] = 65280;    // green
        //intArray[pos] = 16711680; // red
        //intArray[pos] = 255;  // blue

    // test:
    int firstVal = intArray[0];
    std::cout << "values: " << " int: " << firstVal << " R = " <<  ((firstVal >> 16) & 0xff) << " G = " << ((firstVal >> 8) & 0xff) << " B = " << (firstVal  & 0xff) << std::endl;

    // here you create the Mat and use your int array as input
    cv::Mat intMat_BGRA = cv::Mat(imgHeight,imgWidth,CV_8UC4, intArray); 
    // now you have a 4 channel mat with each pixel is one of your int, but with wrong order...
    std::cout << "BGRA ordering: " << intMat_BGRA.at<cv::Vec4b>(0,0) << std::endl;
    // this is in fact the BGRA ordering but you have to remove the alpha channel to get BGR values:
    // (unless you can live with BGRA values => you have to check whether there is garbage or 0s/255s in the byte area

    // so split the channels...
    std::vector<cv::Mat> BGRA_channels;
    cv::split(intMat_BGRA, BGRA_channels);

    // remove the alpha channel:
    BGRA_channels.pop_back();

    // and merge back to image:
    cv::Mat intMat_BGR;
    cv::merge(BGRA_channels, intMat_BGR);

    std::cout << "BGR ordering: " << intMat_BGR.at<cv::Vec3b>(0,0) << std::endl;

    cv::imshow("ordereed", intMat_BGR);

    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

give me output:

```
values:  int: 8453889 R = 128 G = 255 B = 1
BGRA ordering: [1, 255, 128, 0]
BGR ordering: [1, 255, 128]
```

Comment: Thank you very much; is the fact that it needs to be BGR a part of openCV, or is it because of the way I define the int[]? I mean, hardly anything (that I've come accross) uses BGR instead of RGB...

Comment: Afaik BGR byte order is standard for RGB images in most image libraries (e.g. directX). OpenCV assumes bgr ordering for example when displaying images